# Images downloaded during runtime show broken link icon, on second startup show correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I have a script that downloads images from a target page when I click on a link in my application. When the images are downloaded I want to show them in the browser as Image components. The images download with no problem and are stored in path `src\main\resources\META-INF\resources\images\`. When I try to show the downloaded images I create an Image component: `add(new Image("images/img.png", ""))`. This, however, shows a "image not loaded" icon. When I restart the application server and go to the target URL with the images already downloaded from the previous attempt, they are shown with no problem. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are downloading the image in a source folder. This will not work in production as you will have a JAR or WAR.

You must download the image to a directory on the server and the create a img tag with a URL to the image on the server.

Comment: Can I get a hint as to what would the URL look like in practice? I have downloaded the images outside of the source folder to a separate directory, created an img tag with src attribute, but not sure what is expected to be passed to the src attribute.

Comment: the files must be accessible thought http like: https://yourserver/images/image.png